# I am trying to Download Multiple images as a zip folder but getting error using laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am trying to downloads multiple images as a zip folder but unfortunatly i am getting error please help me how can resolve that thanks.

**getting error**

The file "/home/developer/htdocs/yourstitchart.com/cms/public/uploads/images/58-Digitizing-logo/58-Digitizing-logo.zip" does not exist

please check it https://flareapp.io/share/87ngoJ65

[image]

**InboxController**

```
   public function dowloads($id)
{
     $url = config('yourstitchart.file_url');

     $zip = new ZipArchive;

     $inboxFiles = Inbox::where('id', $id)->first()->file;
     $files = [];
     foreach (json_decode($inboxFiles) as $file) {

         $files[] =$url. $file;
     }
        

         $inbox  = Inbox::find($id);
         $folderName = $inbox->id.'-'.str_replace(' ', '-',$inbox->order_name);
         $zip        = new ZipArchive;
                     $zipFile    = $url .$folderName.'/'.$folderName.'.zip';

     
         if ($zip->open($zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
         {
             //add files into a zip
             foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
     
                 $relativeNameInZipFile = str_replace('full',$key,basename($value));
                 $zip->addFile($value, $relativeNameInZipFile);
             }
 
             $zip->close();
         }
     
         return response()->download($zipFile);
 }
```

**HTML VIEW**

```
     <td>
         @if($digitizingInbox->file)
            <a   href="{{ route('download.inbox',$digitizingInbox->id) }}"  
             class="download btn btn-warning">Download
            </a>
        @endif
     </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want:

```
$zipFile = $folderName.'.zip';
```

Your root is already in the public folder so it tries to add the path to the public folder. That doesn't exist. That is why you get the error.

Or you can try and add the folders from the public folder so for example

```
'uploads/images/58-Digitizing-logo/' . $folderName . '.zip';
```